# What is the difference between Groovy each and forEach?

Tags: groovy, foreach, each

Simple question that I haven't been able to find a simple answer for on the googles:  what is the difference between Groovy's each and forEach loops?

I made a simple example and the syntax and behavior seem identical:

```
    [1, 2].each { println it }
    [1, 2].forEach { println it }
```

Both print:

```
1
2
```

The only example I see of both in the Groovy Language Documentation seems to touch on the difference between lambdas and closures, but I can't relate that to the examples I've tried.

Thank you

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The first distinction between `each()` and `forEach()` is that `each()` is provided by Groovy's GDK, while `forEach()` is provided by Java 8 (so it is not available in prior versions of Java.

Another difference is that `each()` accepts a Groovy closure while `forEach()` accepts a [Consumer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html). From Groovy, this difference is not noticeable because Groovy transparently [coerces](http://www.groovy-lang.org/closures.html#_closure_coercion) the closure to a Consumer.

Comment: I hadn't even thought of that being the Java one! Thanks, that makes sense.